# oauth 2 skydrive access in asp.net web page

Tags: oauth, onedrive

I would like to access skyDrive using REST in my website. I want to retrieve list of files and folders, download, upload and delete files.

I've got a microsoft live management site- clientID and clientSecret.

I am trying to figure out the reason of getting 400 bad request error
 While trying to get access token, refresh token from live services. 
I have also followed sample  from Github but still having same issue.
https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows/tree/master/src/Web/Samples/OAuthServer/Asp.net/OAuthSample

I can forward rest of code if someone thinks can able to resolve it.

Thank you

Thanks a lot!

Comment: More code would be helpful. Make sure you've added your client ID and redirect URL to the wl.init call. The client ID needs to have the full ID (with preceding 0's) to work properly. Are you getting the error after the user enters credentials or before?

Comment: What deos "down vote favorite 6" mean in the beginning of you question?

Comment: need more details about your error, including related code and the whole 400 error response.

Comment: Thank you all for responding to my query. I was getting 400 bad request as the 'code' returned in callback page was expired before it was used to get access token from onedrive. I resolved it by putting code to get access token in callback page.